# ¿Cómo añadir imágenes a un textarea con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un botón

```
<button id="emoji"><img src="emoji.png"></button>
```

Tengo el siguiente código Javascript

```
$(function () {
    $('#emoji1').on('click', function() {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.className = 'emoji';
        img.src = 'stick/kiss.png';
        var text = $('#text');
        text.val(text.val() + img);
    });
})();
```

Quiero que al presionar el botón agregue la imagen en un `<textarea id="text">` y que pueda seguir escribiendo.

Comment: Ya edité la publicación, puso una imagen en lugar de código y ya me tomé la molestia de pasar el código de la imagen. Sería bueno que te des una vuelta por [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y por [acá](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/) para que te familiarices con el sitio.

Comment: > Quiero que al presionar el botón agregue la imagen...
Si no puedes hacerlo en un html estático (porque html no lo soporta), entonces tampoco vas a lograrlo dinámicamente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No puedes hacerlo con `textarea` directamente porque `textarea` por definición sólo admite texto. Lo que podrías hacer es crear tu propio editor de texto enriquecido (RTF), aunque sinceramente te recomendaría que optaras por otras opciones ya extendidas (como TinyMCE) porque es una tarea ardua y compleja.

Esta solución requeriría un `iframe` o un `div` que sea editable, crear tus propios botones que realizarán diferentes funciones y, cuando se vaya a realizar la acción necesaria (mandar el formulario, o que el campo editable pierda el foco), que se actualice el valor del textarea ("invisible") en concreto.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo básico (pulsa en "Enviar formulario" para ver el valor del textarea):

```js
$(function () {
  // cuando se pulse en una image de emoticono, copiarlo al final del texto
  $('.rtf-tools img').on('click', function() {
    var text = $(this).closest(".rtf-box").find(".rtf-text");
    text.html(text.html() + "<img class='emoji' src='" + $(this).attr("src") + "' />");
  });

  // cuando se envia el formulario se actualizan los valores del textarea
  $('form').on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".rtf-text").each(function() {
      var textarea = $(this).closest(".rtf-box").find("textarea");
      textarea.val($(this).html());
      // esto no es necesario, solo para demo
      alert("El valor del textarea es: '" + textarea.val() + "'");
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
.rtf-box {
  width:400px;
  height:190px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.rtf-tools {
  height:40px;
  background:#f0f0f0;
}

.rtf-tools img {
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
  border:1px solid #f0f0f0;
}

.rtf-tools img:hover {
  border:1px solid #ffffff;
  background:#f8f8f8;
  opacity:0.8;
}

.rtf-text {
  height:150px;
  padding:12px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.rtf-text .emoji {
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}

.rtf-box textarea {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="rtf-box">
    <div class="rtf-tools">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/XQVF7d0.png"/><img src="http://i.imgur.com/QAobBr2.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="rtf-text" contenteditable="true">
    </div>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
  <button>Enviar formulario</button>
</form>
```

Pero como puedes ver es muy básico (sólo se pone el emoticono al final y no donde esté el cursor), si realmente quieres crear un RTF más completo eso requeriría bastante más: calcular la posición del cursor para colocar ahí el emoticono, diferentes funcionalidades (negrita, cursiva, etc) y parece que no, pero empieza a sumar y sumar y puede acabar siendo increíblemente grande.

Comment: En realidad el textarea si puede permitir imágenes, con EmojiArea se trabaja un textarea.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz No, `textarea` no permite imágenes. Si te fijas en el código fuente de EmojiArea (o si inspeccionas el código que genera) podrás ver que lo que hace es generar un `div` con `contenteditable` en una manera similar a como yo lo hago en la respuesta.

Comment: Revisa el ejemplo...  Ahí sólo hay un textarea, y el código es sólo Javascript.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz he revisado el ejemplo, he creado un ejemplo propio para ver cómo lo hacía y he mirado el código fuente del plugin. EmojiArea crea un `div` con `contenteditable` y clase "emoji-wysiwyg-editor", esconde el `textarea` y controla los diferentes eventos que suceden en el `div`.

Answer (score 8):

Lo que tratas de hacer no es posible. Una etiqueta tipo `<textarea />` está diseñada para contener texto solamente. Lo que puedes hacer es ponerle a ésta la imagen de fondo, así mismo, hacer el textarea transparent por medio de `background-color: transparent` en CSS.

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
  $('textarea').css('background-image', 'url('+src+')');
});
```

```css
button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:focus { outline: none; }
button img {
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
textarea {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-size: 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .25rem;
  transition: border-color .2s ease;
}
textarea:focus {
  border-color: rgba(108, 153, 208, .7);
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/XQVF7d0.png">
</button>
<br />
<textarea cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: Mira EmojiArea, se trabaja con un textarea.

Comment: Gracias, esto me ha servido y funciona perfecto. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Soy nuevo en esto, agregaré el código abajo y mucha suerte amigo.

Este código lo que hace es que al presionar un emoticon o una imagen en este caso "una imagen tipo las caritas del whatsApp lo que yo utilice" y lo que hace es agregar la misma carita en un `div` y seguir escribiendo al lado de la carita insertada.

Este es el código HTML:

```
<div class="rtf-tools"> 
    <img onclick='insertar_emogi(this)'src="imagenes/1.png"/><img onclick='insertar_emogi(this)' src="imagenes/2.png"/> 
</div>
```

Esta es la parte del SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function insertar_emogi(emo){ 
    document.getElementById('campo').focus();
    document.execCommand('insertHTML',false,'<img id="im" style="width:17px;height:17px;" src='+emo.src+' />') 
} 
</script>
```

Este codigo lo que hace es que al presionar un emoticon o una imagen en este caso"una imagen tipo las caritas del whatsApp lo que yo utilice" y lo que hace es agregar la misma carita en un div y seguir escribiendo al lado de la carita insertada

Comment: A mi esto no me ha funcionado. Yo lo resolví mejor con la respuesta de MitsuG

Answer (score 1):

Con textarea puede que no se pueda(se podrían usar iconos si están incluidos en los caracteres de una fuente), pero por medio de un div editable si es posible añadir iconos personalizados.

[Ejemplo por andrewfiorillo](https://codepen.io/andrewfiorillo/pen/wgmnB)